# Using WHERE with a window function in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

For context, I'm using an SQLite DB via Python to store diagnostic information for of a number of devices, which gets logged to the database every week. One useful piece of data I'd like to extract is *when* each device's status changes.

I can write a query like

```
SELECT 
    date,
    lightID,
    (status - LAG(status, 1)) OVER (ORDER BY date) as statusChange
FROM devices
```

but this only gets me partway, as if `statusChange` is 0 then the status hasn't actually changed at all. The obvious next step would be to filter using a WHERE clause, but attempting to use a WHERE clause which filters over a window function gives me a "misuse of aliased window function" error.

How could I filter over an aliased window function, or at least simulate doing so?

Comment: Each time the status changes write the date to a table then use a WHERE clause a dates between two dates OR a date that is one week old and greater than that date IF you do not know how to write a WHERE statement then let us know

Comment: Put the first query in a CTE or subquery and select from it?